# Can partially constant functions be analytic?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a nonconstant real analytic function on $(a,b).$ Can $f$ be constant on a nonempty subinterval $(c,d)$ of $(a,b)?$

I already know that this kind of function can be smooth, seeing an [example on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness),  let
\begin{align}
f:(0,2)&\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
x&\mapsto \left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)&\quad& \text{if } x<1\\
&0&\quad& \text{if }x\geq1.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
And we have that $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty((0,2))$.

Comment: If $c = d$. Otherwise, the identity theorem says that if a real-analytic function is constant on some non-degenerate subinterval of $(a,b)$ [even stronger, if it's constant on any subset of $(a,b)$ that has an accumulation point in $(a,b)$], then it's globally constant.

Comment: Note your example of a smooth function has errors.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks! (if it was the minus sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. Note that we can assume $a=c$. Let $s$ be supremum of the real numbers $x$ such that $f$ is constant of $(a,x)$. Your assumption is equivalent to $s>a$. I claim $s=b$, which will finish the proof.

Suppose $a<s<b$ (for contradiction). $f$ is analytic at $s$, and left-sided derivatives of any order at $s$ are equal to $0$. This means that all coefficients of power series defining $f$ around $s$ are equal to $0$, so $f$ is $0$ on some neighbourhood $(s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)$ of $s$. But then $f$ is constant on $(a,s+\varepsilon)$, which is impossible as $s+\varepsilon>s$.

Answer (score 0):

**Only an idea:** All harmonic functions are analytic, i.e. they can be locally expressed as power series. This is a general fact about elliptic operators, of which the Laplacian is a major example. By Wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function).

So, I think that you can use this + the Maximum/Minimum Principle.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. In order to be useful you'd need that every real analytic function is harmonic, why would that be true?

Comment: I don't say that. The function of the problem is constant in a interval, so it is harmonic in $(c,d)$. Maybe, with the Maximum/Minimum Principle we can extend the result for $(a,b)$. It's only an idea.

Answer (score 0):

For $f$ to be analytic on $(a,b)$, the Taylor series has to be the same regardless of what point you expand about, and here's a hint: what does the Taylor series look like when you expand about a point $\xi\in(c,d)$?

Comment: $(c,d)\subsetneq(a,b)$ so no.

Comment: @Fabian First I forgot to specify that $f$ is non-constant. So that explains his 'short answer'. Now my question is fixed. =)

Comment: $\xi\in(a,b)$ so we certainly can expand the Taylor series about the point...

Comment: The answer to the question should still be no... (even the short answer)